# How to get last new row of a growing CSV file?

Tags: excel, vba

I export data from a software to a CSV file, and the CSV file get new row every 5 minutes. Then, I want to get the newest row into another CSV or Excel file. No need to keep history, but need the newest row to be updated on real time.

How can I do this?

Comment: So the CSV file is automatically updated, or manually updated by your data export? How does this update happen? And then you want only the updated row in a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

A way to take into account updates of a growing file is:

- seek to end of file
- poll until file size increases
- read file from previous EOF up to current EOF
- make anything pleases you with that data
- repeat from poll step (you already are at the end of file)

CSV to Excel conversion can be found elsewhere on SO.

Comment: sorry I'm short of knowledge about excel, I don't understand the method you provided without code example. By the way, csv to csv or csv to excel, it doesn't matter. I only need the new row in another spreadsheet.